# For an analytic function $f(z)=u+iv$, if $u=e^x(x \cos y-y \sin x)$ find $v$.

Tags: complex-analysis

For an analytic function $f(z)=u+iv$, if $u=e^x(x \cos y-y \sin x)$ find $v$.

How to solve it? I have used CR equation but have failed to get desired result.
Please help.

Comment: Just to check, are you sure it is $e^{x}(x\cos(y)-y\sin(x)$ and not $e^{x}(x\cos(y)-y\sin(y)$?

Comment: Take the imaginary part of $ze^{z}$.

Comment: @LordVader007 Yes I have checked. Is $e^x(xcos(y)−ysin(x)$ wrong?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It works fine. How to get $f(z)=ze^z$ mathematically?

Comment: @user1942348 Since $z=x+iy$ and $e^z=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$, $ze^z=e^x(x\cos y-y\sin y+i(x\sin y+y\cos y))$. The real part of this is what $u$ would be if the $\sin x$ were changed to $\sin y$.

Comment: @J.G. Right... what to do then... Search for another function?

Comment: @user1942348 the function as written originally fails to be harmonic

Comment: @LordVader007 Ok.. that means question is wrong?

Comment: @user1942348 I'm willing to bet money that there's a typo. You can't do this finding of $v$ unless the original function $u$ is harmonic. That is, it satisfies Laplace's equation AND is of class $C^2$, that is all of its second partial derivatives exist and are continuous.

Comment: @LordVader007 Thank you. I understand

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the fact that $e^{z}=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}=e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))$ and $z=x+iy$. Then construct a function $f(z)$ such that $\Re{f(z)}=u(x,y)$. The harmonic conjugate is then the imaginary part...

Edit: Think of ways you can construct such an $f(z)$. Try multiplying $e^z$ by another function such that its real part is what you have. It should be clear what you have to multiply by.

So there is, by the way, a method to calculate the $f(z)$. To get the function into the form $f(z)$, we realize that $f'(z) = \cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+i\cfrac{\partial v}{\partial x}= \cfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}-i\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$. Moreover, since we are given $u(x,y)$, we can write $f'(z)$ as a function of $x,y$.

This amounts to integrating to get $f(z) = \int_{z=x,y=0} f'(z)dz$, where the $f'(z)$ is obtained by the formula I gave with the partial derivatives. Note that the *integrand* is evaluated along $z=x$ and $y=0$.

Example: Let $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ so we find an *analytic* $f(z)$ such that $\Re{f(z)}=u(x,y)$. Differentiating, we get $u_x=2x$ and $u_y=-2y$. Thus, by the formula, $f'(z)=2x-i(-2y)=2(x+iy)$. Thus, using the integration trick, we'd get:

$f(z) = \int_{z=x,y=0} 2(x+iy)dz= \int 2z dz=z^2+C$

Comment: Please write in more details to get $f(z)$

Comment: Please check my post now.