# Given $u(x,y) = e^x (x \cos y - y \sin y)$ for analytic $f(z) = u + iv$, find $v(x,y)$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, analytic-functions

Given $u(x,y) = e^x (x \cos y - y \sin y)$ for analytic $f(z) = u + iv$, find $v(x,y)$. I know that there is an answer to this question in [For an analytic function $f(z)=u+iv$, if $u=e^x(x \cos y-y \sin x)$ find $v$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672427/for-an-analytic-function-fz-uiv-if-u-exx-cos-y-y-sin-x-find-v).
But it seems to me that approach used there is specific to the problem (the choice of the integration path). Is it? If not, could you exlain how the integration path is chosen?
If it is, could you exlain what the general approach is to solve such problems? I know, I should check if $u$ is harmonic, then I should find the harmonic conjugate of $u$ but I don't know what path to choose (usually I'd take the line connecting $(0,0)$ and $(x,y)$. In this case it results in rather complicated integrals so I think there has to be a better path to integrate over. A clarification would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is perhaps a more general approach.

Define $v(x,y)=\int_{0}^{y}u_{x}(x,t)\,dt+\phi(x)$ to be a guess for $v$. (We are guessing like this as $v$ must satisfy the CR equations).

Where $\phi$ is some arbitrary function of $x$.

then $v_{y}=u_{x}$ and $v_{x}=\int_{0}^{y}u_{xx}(x,t)\,dt+\phi'(x)$.

Now by Harmonicity of $u$ we get

$$v_{x}=-\int_{0}^{y}u_{yy}(x,t)\,dt+\phi'(x)=u_{y}(x,0)-u_{y}(x,y)+\phi'(x)$$

So if CR equations are to be satisfied then $u_{y}(x,0)+\phi'(x)$ should be $0$.

So you can solve the ODE in above and set $\phi(x)=-\int_{0}^{x}u_{y}(t,0)dt$

Thus $v(x,y)=\int_{0}^{y}u_{x}(x,t)\,dt-\int_{0}^{x}u_{y}(t,0)dt$

Comment: Thank you for such an elegant solution. The only thing I don't understand is why $f(x)$ is being added in the definition of $v$. Isn't $v(x,y)$ equal to that integral on the right side?

Comment: Oh ok, that integral is actually equal to $v(x,y) - v(x,0)$, isn't it? But then $f(x) = u(x,0) + iv(x,0)$, how do they cancel out to become $v(x,y)$?

Comment: Sorry....I think you might be confused by my notation. I took $f(x)$ to be an arbitrary function which comes after solving the PDE $v_{y}=u_{x}$. It is not related to the original $f$ in the question.

Comment: Add a couple of $dx$ and $dt$.

Comment: Now I see it, thanks!

Comment: @Gary I've edited thanks